# How do I set onUpdate for a foreign key from the Fluent API?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get a foreign key relationship in Entity Framework 7 to apply both `ON DELETE CASCADE` and `ON UPDATE CASCADE` on the sql constraint.

When using the model builder in `OnModelCreating` I'm able to specify the relationship to use cascade on deletion. It's finding out where to specify the update action that I need help.

Here is my sample model code:

```
class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("...connection string...");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Post)
            .WithMany(p => p.Comments)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.PostName)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); 
            //if you delete the post, delete its comments

        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasKey(c => new { c.Number, c.PostName });
    }
}

class Post
{
    [Required, Key, StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Contents { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

class Comment
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    public string PostName { get; set; }
    public string Contents { get; set; }
}
```

When I run `Add-Migration First`, this is the generated code for the `Up` method.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Post",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
        Contents = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Post", x => x.Name);
    });
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Comment",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Number = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
        PostName = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
        Contents = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Comment", x => new { x.Number, x.PostName });
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Comment_Post_PostName",
            column: x => x.PostName,
            principalTable: "Post",
            principalColumn: "Name",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade
            // ,onUpdate: ReferentialAction.Cascade
            );
    });
```

Note that the last parameter is commented out; I added this manually afterwards. If I uncomment the line, the created sql table **does** have `ON UPDATE CASCADE` applied.

Right now I need to manually alter my migration files to add update cascade support. Is there a way within the Fluent API that I can have the migration engine add `onUpdate: ReferentialAction.Cascade` for me when the migration file is created?

[Searching through the github code](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=OnUpdate&type=Code) gives some interesting results, and is also how I figured out that manually editing the migration file would work.

In the `CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator` class, the [`Generate`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/cd2872cfe618bb9445df2a6342eb914ada479c3f/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Core/Migrations/Design/CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator.cs#L132) method that deals with `AddForeignKeyOperation` [has a section](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/cd2872cfe618bb9445df2a6342eb914ada479c3f/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Core/Migrations/Design/CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator.cs#L183) for writing `onUpdate:`, so the generator must have the ability to write the value I need. How do I trigger it?

---

In attempt to an answer given, I added the following after the creation of the foreign key in `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
    .Property(p => p.PostName)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```

The migration created was identical to the migration created without this code, and thus no change in the resulting sql table.

Answer (score 0):

This had me stuck for a while too. You need to access the property itself in order to do this.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
   .Property(c => c.YourProperty)
   .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```

It's confusing but if you read the description of this in Visual Studio it will shed some light on what it does.

Comment: This didn't produce any difference in the migration. I added details to my post.